# Spring JPA Equal conditon with derived query for LocalDate not working

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Oracle DB with type of `DATE` my Entiy class have `LocalDate` parameter as shown in here

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTRACT")
public class ContractEntity {
    private Long id;
    private LocalDate contractStartDate;
    private LocalDate contractEndDate;
    ...
```

For the testing I created derived query to find Entity by `contractStartDate`

```
public interface ContractRepository extends JpaRepository<ContractEntity, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<ContractEntity> {
            ContractEntity getContractEntityByContractStartDateIs(LocalDate date)
}
```

Then I created Two Tests as follows;

```
 @DisplayName("Should get Exact Date  Entity")
    @Test
    void test1(){
        LocalDate date=LocalDate.of(2021,03,9);
        ContractEntity entity= searchService.getByDate(date); // getByDate is mapped to getContractEntityByContractStartDateIs() in service layer
        assertEquals(date,entity.getContractStartDate());
    }



    @DisplayName("Should match ID:1 Entity's Date with Local Date")
    @Test
    void test2(){
        ContractEntity entity=searchService.getById(1l).get(); 
        assertEquals(1l,entity.getId());
        LocalDate date=LocalDate.of(2021,03,9);
        assertEquals(date,entity.getContractStartDate());
    }

}
```

My problem is **test1** fails with null error which means equality condition fails to give existence of that Entity even though **test2** passed which `date` is equal to id:1 entity's Start-date

p.s: I have set Contract Table's ID:1  **Contract Start Date** value to **2021,03,9** as shown in image here
[image]

So what would be the reason for this Why **test1** fails to get equal entity and why **test2** pass that assert equity of date is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LocalDate` doesn't contain a time component, but the data type you used in the database does and it is not `0` for the data in the database.

In order to make the comparison (which happens in the database) the `LocalDate` gets converted with a date + time where the time is probably `0`, which is not equal to the date+times present in the database.

When the entity gets loaded the time part of the database value gets dropped and the result is equal to your `LocalDate` value.

Comment: Thank you that was the reason I change the time to 00:00:00 and it woks